# Find And Replace strings containing a caret

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace, microsoft-word-2013

Consider a string to be replaced in Microsoft Word

```
Foo^Bar
```

Using the Find and Replace dialog, Word interprets a caret(`^`) character as a [control character to help find predefined elements in your Word document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214204).

How can I escape this process and actually find and replace a string containing a caret?

[image]

> ^B is not a valid special character for the Find What box

Using an escape like `Foo\^Bar` doesn't work. What can be used to escape this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried it in Office 2007.

Use `Foo^^Bar` as your search string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape it with an extra `^`.

`Foo^^Bar` will search for `Foo^Bar`